# Firebase Facebook Login User.uid is nil

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I implemented the Facebook Login through Firebase but I'm getting the error that `user.uid` is nil.

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
    if user == nil || user!.uid.isEmpty { 
        print("User UID is nil")
    }
)}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try printing out the errormessage: `print(error.localizedDescription)`

Comment: The problem is that I'm can't reproduce this error, but this is happening from the Apple side while reviewing the app.

Comment: Without seeing the [minimal code to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at least the error message, it will be hard to help.